# Nginx sever not handling 404 from upstreams

Tags: nginx, tomcat

In my setup , 
I have a nginx server as a reverse proxy for my tomcat application servers. 
I use proxy_pass to connect to tomcat upstreams ..

```
location /test {
         proxy_pass http://upstream1/webapp1/gateway
}
```

Now if some one fires a request to my nginx server http://myserver.com/test.jsp , this request is also handled by the test location and passed to the tomcat instance.

The tomcat instance returns a 404,but nginx is not handling this 404 request . ( I already have pages defined for 404 in nginx level) ,instead the browser show the page directly from tomcat(with tomcat version information and all) . 
How can i block this. I dont want to expose my application server details.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell nginx to intercept upstream errors with [`proxy_intercept_errors`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive.

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://upstream1/webapp1/gateway;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
```